# android upload image to server using php

Tags: php, android

I am trying to upload image which is captured by android camera to server using php script.
However, one error occur.

The relevant codes are:

```
// upload photo to server
boolean uploadPhoto(FileInputStream fileInputStream) {
    Log.i(TAG,"step into uploadPhoto");

    final String serverFileName = (int) Math
        .round(Math.random() * 1000) + ".jpg";
    Log.i(TAG, "the name of uploaded image is " + serverFileName);
    final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    final String twoHyphens = "--";
    final String boundary = "*****";

    try {
    URL url = new URL(SERVERURL);
    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
    final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
        .openConnection();
    // Allow Inputs
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Allow Outputs
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    // Don't use a cached copy.
    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    // Use a post method.
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
        conn.getOutputStream());

    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
        + serverFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    // create a buffer of maximum size
    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    int maxBufferSize = 1024;
    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // read file and write it into form...
    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    // send multipart form data after file data...
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
    publishProgress(SERVER_PROC_STATE);
    // close streams
    fileInputStream.close();
    dos.flush();
    Log.i(TAG, "upload succeddfully");
    conn.disconnect();
    return true;
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);        
    return false;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);      
    return false;
    }
}
```

The php script is:

```
<?php
....
$photo_upload_path = "./upload/";
$photo_upload_path = $photo_upload_path. basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(copy($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $photo_upload_path)) {
    .....
}
....
?>
```

The error in the Apache error log is

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: uploadedfile
```

BUT, I have made declaration in the uploadPhoto function.

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
        + serverFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
```

I have no idea. Any suggestion for this error？
I also output the $_FILES and $_POST in the php script.Both the two variables are empty.In the Apache error log, the error information exists as well. And in the Apache access log, the server response code is 200. I have really no idea about what happened and how to fix it.

Comment: you can check the traffic if you put in your PHP-script an `print_r($_FILES)` and maybe an `print_r($_POST)` and in your android code Log the response. In these cases it is difficult to find the error just from the code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have tested some methods. But, the error exists as well. I also create a test.html that allow me upload image manually.It works well. So the bug may exist at the android side...      I don't know why the $_FILES['uploadfile']['temp_name'] is null

Comment: I also output the $_FILES and $_POST in the php script.Both the two variables are empty.In the Apache error log, the error information exists as well. And in the Apache access log, the server response code is 200. I have really no idea about what happened and how to fix it.